# Mongodb $Sort over created and updated date. (Which one is latest)

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query

I know how to sort documents using MongoDB. But I want to sort documents over multiple date attributes like sort on created and updated date which one is latest. For example document is newly created or recently updated, it should be come first.

here is my document sample.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5720b6f0bb700f8839fc6972"),
    "name" : "Tov Kosher Kitchen",
    "restaurant_id" : "40356068",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-05-05T07:02:13.137Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-05-05T07:02:58.033Z")
}
```

**Update:** createdAt and updatedAt are sample attributes. Both can be changed independent of each other.

Comment: What do you mean by *sort on created and updated date which one is latest*?

Comment: Like if admin change created date to current date time-stamp then it should come first, if he change updated date to current date then it should come first is sort result. make sense?

Comment: It's simply not possible to sort all your documents like that.

Comment: Show us what you have tried to make this work. Else it won't be possible to help you.

Comment: i agree with @user3100115 you cannot perform a sort like this, you can only sort by EITHER createdAt or updatedAt, or one property first then the next property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `aggregate` by using a `$project` stage that adds a field which is the greater of the two timestamps and then sorting on that:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        // Include the original doc
        doc: '$$ROOT',
        // Add a 'latest' field that contains the greater of createdAt and updateAt
        latest: {$cond: {
            if: {$gt: ['$createdAt', '$updatedAt']},
            then: '$createdAt',
            else: '$updatedAt'
        }}
    }},
    {$sort: {latest: -1}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you set both the "updatedAt" date and "createdAt" date when the document is created (or when the createdAt date is set). Then you can just sort by updatedAt.

Comment: yes, going forward this is probably the best way to go about it...can't imagine why updatedAt would ever be before createdAt

Answer (score 0):

Since this can't be done with a sort, another option you have is writing a script that compares updatedAt and createdAt for each document and writes a new property to the document called "mostRecentDate" which is the most recent date of updatedAt and createdAt.

Then sort by "mostRecentDate," make sure any future writes or updates changes this property and other date property.